# Entering subdirectories (with spaces) and merge the files to another directory

Tags: bash, directory-traversal

I want to do something special in bash. I have found partial solutions with for loops and find, but I prefer to make a script to make a more complex job.

I have a complex directory structure as follows:

```
fiction/
 book1/
  chapter1/
   page1.txt
   page2.txt
   ..
  chapter2/
   page5.txt
   page6.txt
  ..
 book2/
  chapter1/
  chapter2/
 ..
non-fiction/
 book5/
  chapter1/
..
```

I hope you get the point.

In short I want to do the following:

1. Enter each book and chapter, such as Chapter1
2. cat all the page1, page2 etc in /mybooks/book1/chapter1.txt
3. proceed to the next chapter, and repeat for /mybooks/book1/chapter2.txt
4. proceed to the next book

I managed to do this with the simple script:

```
for i in */; do cat "$i"*.txt > /newdir/"${i%%/}".txt; done
```

My first problem showed up when I realised there are books divided not only in chapters, but also in parts or subsections themselves containing chapters. The only solution was to cd to those folders and perform the script manually.

But this is not the professional way. How can I make the script more intelligent to traverse subdirectories and then move back?

Answer (score 0):

you might try something like:

```
for b in */*
do 
  cat $(find "$b" -type f -name \*.txt| sort) >> "$b"/$(basename "$b").txtb
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer...

- handles directories with spaces
- sorts pages correct in case you have more than 9 pages in a chapter

---

It is based on these assumptions:

- pages are always immediately below chapter*
- pages are named page[one or more digit].txt
- there's just one part that matches "chapter*" in a path, so nothing like "chapter2/subchapter1"

---

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r -d $'\0' path; do
    output="$path".txt
    ls -1 "$path"/page*.txt | \
     sed 's/^.*\([0-9][0-9]*\).txt/\1/' | \
     sort -n | \
     while read n; do
         echo "cat ${path}/page${n}.txt >> $output"
         # cat "${path}/page${n}.txt" >> "$output"
     done
done < <(find fiction/ -type d -name "chapter*" -print0)
```

---

When happy with the result delete the `echo`-line and uncomment the one below.

#### Example:

```
find f
f
f/book2
f/book2/chapter1
f/book2/chapter1/page10.txt
f/book2/chapter1/page2.txt
f/book2/chapter1/page1.txt
f/book2/chapter3
f/book2/chapter3/page2.txt
f/book2/chapter3/page1.txt
f/book2/chapter2
f/book2/chapter2/page2.txt
f/book2/chapter2/page1.txt
f/book2/part1
f/book2/part1/subsection1
f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1
f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1/page2.txt
f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1/page3.txt
f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1/page1.txt
f/book1
f/book1/chapter1
f/book1/chapter1/page2.txt
f/book1/chapter1/page1.txt
f/book1/chapter3
f/book1/chapter3/page2.txt
f/book1/chapter3/page1.txt
f/book1/chapter2
f/book1/chapter2/page2.txt
f/book1/chapter2/page1.txt
f/book with space
f/book with space/chapter1
f/book with space/chapter1/page2.txt
f/book with space/chapter1/page1.txt
```

#### Output:

```
cat f/book2/chapter1/page1.txt >> f/book2/chapter1.txt
cat f/book2/chapter1/page2.txt >> f/book2/chapter1.txt
cat f/book2/chapter1/page10.txt >> f/book2/chapter1.txt
cat f/book2/chapter3/page1.txt >> f/book2/chapter3.txt
cat f/book2/chapter3/page2.txt >> f/book2/chapter3.txt
cat f/book2/chapter2/page1.txt >> f/book2/chapter2.txt
cat f/book2/chapter2/page2.txt >> f/book2/chapter2.txt
cat f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1/page1.txt >> f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1.txt
cat f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1/page2.txt >> f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1.txt
cat f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1/page3.txt >> f/book2/part1/subsection1/chapter1.txt
cat f/book1/chapter1/page1.txt >> f/book1/chapter1.txt
cat f/book1/chapter1/page2.txt >> f/book1/chapter1.txt
cat f/book1/chapter3/page1.txt >> f/book1/chapter3.txt
cat f/book1/chapter3/page2.txt >> f/book1/chapter3.txt
cat f/book1/chapter2/page1.txt >> f/book1/chapter2.txt
cat f/book1/chapter2/page2.txt >> f/book1/chapter2.txt
cat f/book with space/chapter1/page1.txt >> f/book with space/chapter1.txt
cat f/book with space/chapter1/page2.txt >> f/book with space/chapter1.txt
```